# Ruby: Get length of the longest string

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings, `stringarr`, and want to know the length of the longest string. I'm not interested in the string itself.

My first solution was

```
maxlen = stringarr.max_by(&:size).size
```

Works, but ugly: I have to mention size twice, which is error-prone, and the size of the longest string needs to be caluclated twice. Well, no big deal with strings, but see below.

Another idea was

```
maxlen = stringarr.map(&:size).max
```

Cleaner from the viewpoint of readability, but needs to create a temporary array. Not good either.

Here another attempt:

```
maxlen = stringarr.inject(0) {|memo,s| [memo.size,s.size].max}
```

Not exactly beautiful either....

I wonder if there is a better approach. My wish would be something like

```
maxlen = stringarr.max_of(&:size) # Sadly no max_of in Ruby core
```

This would be of interest in particular, when I have a more complicated code block. This certainly is not good style:

```
maxlen = measurement(stringarr.max_by {|s| measurement(s)})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are you asking us here?  are you looking for the most performant way to do this?  Your comments in your question are _opinions_ on what _looks_ better...

Comment: do you need the strings afterwards? If not you could use `map!` which will not create a "temporary array" it will modify the existing one.

Comment: @Anthony: I'm looking not so much for *opinions* for a solution which is maintainable and at least not outright inefficient. Maintainability for instance means that no code duplication is better than code duplication, so my first attempt (where I had to write `size` twice is not so good), and inefficiency means for instance that the operations gets expensive for large arrays if I have to construct a temporary array; that's why my second attempt is not so good. So, I'm not looking so much for personal opinions, but for results which can be objectively discussed.

Comment: @MaximFedotov : I just don't quite see, how a JavaScript algorithm could help me here. Could you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: @engineersmnky : Good point, but, yes, I still need the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Stole</strike> compiled @msergeant and @sebastián-palma:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 10_000
stringarr = Array.new( N, 'Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet' )

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { stringarr.map(&:size).max }
  x.report { stringarr.max_by(&:size).size }
  x.report { stringarr.sort_by(&:size)[-1].size }
  x.report { stringarr.inject(0) { |memo,s| [memo,s.size].max } }
  x.report { stringarr.inject(0) { |memo,s| memo > s.size ? memo : s.size } }
end
```

My winner is @msergeant's variant with using ternary operator, when bare `[memo,s.size].max` is a slowest one. You can have different results on your environment and with another `stringarr`'s data.

Comment: the quickest solution is O(n) time with O(1) space:  def max(arr)
  max = arr[0].size
  arr.each { |i| max = i.size if i.size > max }
  max
end

Answer (score 3):

I think your `inject` method is probably the cleanest, but it has an error in it. You memoize the size but then you call `.size` on the memoized number.

Try this instead:

```
maxlen = stringarr.inject(0) {|memo,s| [memo,s.size].max}
```

Comment: Right you are! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers and comments I received, I decided to add a method to `Enumerable` for this purpose. I'm posting it here, in case someone wants to take benefit from it, or in contrary criticize it:

```
class Enumerable

  # Similar to map(&block).max, but more efficient
  # 
  # x.max_of {|s| f(s)} returns the largest value f(s), or nil if x is empty.
  # x(seed).max_of {|s| f(s)} returns the largest value f(s), provided that it 
  #                           is larger than seed, or returns seed, if no such
  #                           element exists or x is empty.
  def max_of(seed = nil)
    enumerator = each
    result = nil
    begin
      if seed
        result = seed
      else
        result = yield(enumerator.next)
      end
      loop do
        next_val = yield(enumerator.next)
        result = next_val if next_val > result
      end
    rescue StopIteration
    end
    result
  end

end
```